# How can I make edits to a single xml node in android

Tags: android, xml

I need a fast way to save edits to an xml file any examples would be greatly appreciated I assume this would be using xpath? thanks

[EDIT] I am currently using documentBuilder.parse() but that takes far too long, approximately 20 seconds to read the file

Answer (score 0):

I can give you example in QT..I don't know in what language are you working with. Here is for QT:

```
QDomDocument doc("MyML");
 QDomElement root = doc.createElement("MyML");
 doc.appendChild(root);

 QDomElement tag = doc.createElement("Greeting");
 root.appendChild(tag);

 QDomText t = doc.createTextNode("Hello World");
 tag.appendChild(t);

 QString xml = doc.toString();
```

If I didn't get you right please respond. And maybe we can sort it out.

Comment: sorry I didn't say - its in Java, Ideally android 2.1 but I have seen something about x path in v2.2 which may be an acceptable compromise. thanks